# How do I stop Skype putting presence indicators in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, skype

Skype has started putting little squares next to people's names in Outlook indicating whether they are online or not. I would like to turn this off, yet I cannot find it as an option in Skype anywhere, or as a plugin in Outlook.

I have Outlook 2010, Skype 6.1.0.129 on Windows 7.

How do I stop it?

Comment: Does it not appear in Outlook -File -> Add-ins

Comment: If you mean Add-ins under File->Options then no.

Comment: I can't see it, either under Skype or under Microsoft Office/Outllok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method via registry editing. Only do this if you know what you're doing and understand what editing the registry can mean.

Delete the newly added registry key at `\HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\IM Providers\DefaultIMApp` (Skype sets the value to ‘Skype’ and also adds some sub keys). If this fails AFTER a restart, then set the DefaultIMApp value to ‘NotSkype’ at `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Softare\IM Providers\`.

[image]

[Source](http://thomasloughlin.com/remove-skype-outlook-integration/)

Comment: I simply changed the DefaultIMApp key to "NotSkype" and restarted Outlook, and the unwanted presence indicators are now gone.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if the presence indicators are because of Skype but I was able to remove them by following the steps below:

1. Go to File -> Options.
2. Select "Contacts" on the left side toolbar.
3. Under "Online status and photographs" deselect "Display online status next to name"

Comment: FYI, the presence indicators are for Skype.  I also believe turning this off will stop Outlook from repeatedly crashing.

Answer (score 3):

You can try disabling the "Microsoft Outlook Social Connector" add-in under File -> Options without changing the registry.

It is possible to fully uninstall the Add-in via Add or Remove programs dialog, when you go to Microsoft Office 2010 and select Change. Then you locate the add-in under Outlook->Add-ins.

It will require computer restart.

Comment: The Social Connector isn't enabled and yet I'm still getting the indicators.